# How to display week numbers on a chart's axis

Tags: charts, time, calendar, timeline

I have time series data visualized on a line chart and want to format the x-axis accordingly. I wonder what format to choose in English if the data is aggregated by week. In German I would use "KW x".

- I found [this discussion](https://goo.gl/ENrRxm) that suggests "Week x" if you want to translate the German word "Kalenderwoche (KW) x" to English.
- Google calendar is also using this format.

[image: Week 10 in popup]

- Moment.js offers some other options

[image: w, wo, ww]

Anyone else has any input on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Week x” is good, though “[wk](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/wk) x” will also work if you don’t have space for two more letters. It’s an established abbreviation that can be found in any dictionary and is clear enough in context.

For a graph, my preference would be to just have a number associated with each tick on the x-axis and then label the axis “Week of the year”.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what programs you use but excel can give you a week number based on a date, assume cell A1 has the relevant date then :

```
="Week "&week(A1))
```

Will give :
Week 7

If the date is in week 7... 
the text in double quotes can be what you want but notice the space at the end...

Then just produce the relevant ones you need for the chart.

Of course if you have a function that gets the relevant translation of "week" in cell B1 then you could use:

```
=B1&" "&A1
```

which would give "Week 7" or "KW 7" or "Semaine 7" etc

Comment: `week()` should never be used without its second parameter that specifies the conventions used, because the defaulte one is wrong for most locales.